# Spring boot: Handling mongodb timeoutException

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

When Mongodb is down, the spring boot  application is down. I wish to handle exception  of connectiontimeout and log the error without stopping application.
When finding an item from database is failed because the connection is not possible, the application should do another treatment like calling web service to find data.
Did you have any idea about this ?

Configuration

> spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://${MONGODB_DB_HOST}:${MONGODB_DB_PORT}/${MONGODB_DB_DATABASE}?connectTimeoutMS=${mongodb.connection.timeout}

Comment: Springboot is by design failfast. So it depends on several things
1. When do you wish to do it during startup or later
2. How is your mongoconfiguration, is it one by SpringBoot AutoConfiguration or you are configuring it manually.

Comment: My configuration is by spring boot Auto configuration.    
And i wish to call web service when the search from  from database is failed.
I updated my question with the configuration

Comment: So i wish to handle exception after startup

Comment: If you are using AutoConfiguration, then springboot will start even if it cannot connect to mongo(it prints stacktrace though).So why can't you just put a try catch against the code where you are trying to find an item? Or create an aspect for the exception thrown and do the necesessary action

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code to configure mongodb connection in spring boot

you can specify socket timeout and connection timeout according to your need.

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);


    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String mongoDbName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {

        LOGGER.debug(" instantiating MongoDbFactory ");

        SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient(), mongoDbName);

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);

        return mongoTemplate;

    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {

        List<ServerAddress> servers = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
        servers.add(new ServerAddress(host, port));

        MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .connectionsPerHost(10)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .build();

        if (Utils.isNotEmpty(username) && Utils.isNotEmpty(password)) {
            List<MongoCredential> creds = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
            creds.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(username, mongoDbName, password.toCharArray()));
            return new MongoClient(servers,creds, mongoClientOptions);
        } else
            return new MongoClient(servers, mongoClientOptions);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClientURI mongoClientURI() {
        LOGGER.debug(" creating connection with mongodb with uri [{}] ", mongoUri);
        return new MongoClientURI(mongoUri);
    }

}
```

Define below properties in your application.yml file

## mongodb specific properties

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: dbname
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      username: dbusername
      password: dbpassword
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below sample example to configure mongodb timeout. I hope it's easy to convert to bean annonation for springboot. Else you can import the resource bean (@ImportResource)

```
<beans>

  <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017">
    <mongo:options connections-per-host="8"
                   threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
                   connect-timeout="1000"
                   max-wait-time="1500}"
                   auto-connect-retry="true"
                   socket-keep-alive="true"
                   socket-timeout="1500"
                   slave-ok="true"
                   write-number="1"
                   write-timeout="0"
                   write-fsync="true"/>
  </mongo:mongo/>

</beans>
```

Comment: how does it answer the question of handling exception. This configuration is just setting timeout on mongo connection. This can be doen from properties file itself.

Comment: Sorry this cannot answer my question. I wish to handle MongoTimeoutException .

Comment: @NAZEHA , do you come out an answer after 5 year? same issuer here